# Password not working in Bitcoin core wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, passphrase

I am trying to transfer my BTC to another wallet and it is saying my passphrase is incorrect when I know it is not and use this password for a few things. Any ideas to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Any ideas to get around this?**

- Check the computer for viruses.
- Disconnect the computer from the network
- Type the password/passphrase into Notepad (etc) where you can see it, then cut&paste into the wallet prompt.
- Restore the wallet from one of your recent backups and retry.
- Restore the wallet from one of your older backups and retry.
- Restore the wallet from one of your offsite backups and retry.
- Fetch one of your written notes of the private key from the safety-deposit box at the bank or from your floor-safe, use it to re-create the wallet and then create a new password.